# Mysql : Calculating median on joined table

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, median

I have 2 Tables ...
each TABLE1's record has multiple scores on TABLE2 and I need to get Median value of each TABLE1 record from TABLE2

How can I combine these two queries ?

Simple Join Query :

```
SELECT *
  FROM `TABLE1` 
  LEFT JOIN `TABLE2` ON `TABLE2`.`table1_id` = `TABLE1`.`id`
```

Median Query :

```
SET @rowindex := -1;
 SELECT
   AVG(g.scores)
FROM
   (SELECT @rowindex:=@rowindex + 1 AS rowindex,
           TABLE2.scores AS scores
    FROM TABLE2
    ORDER BY TABLE2.scores) AS g
WHERE
g.rowindex IN (FLOOR(@rowindex / 2) , CEIL(@rowindex / 2));
```

Comment: Do you need a median or an average? Notice that they are different mathematical concepts. I'm asking because in your "median" query you are using the average aggregating function.

Comment: I found that query from another page and I was not 100% sure about its result , and yes I need the median value